# Aggregate methods to use with IEnumerable lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, ienumerable

Is there a way to "convert" (return) an IEnumerable list of, e.g., strings to an IEnumerable list of a different type when that different type accepts the former type in its constructor?

For example, the `DataTable.Columns.AddRange()` method accepts only lists of columns. Is there a way to return a `DataColumn` list by offering a `string` list using LINQ or some sort of aggregate function? I imagine the code would roughly do the following, but in one line:

```
var columnList = new List<DataColumn>();
foreach (var item in myStringList)
{
    columnList.Add(item);
}
return columnList;
```

Likewise, is there an aggregate method that will take a list and run each of its members against a specific method? For example, I am looking for a one line way to perform the following similar `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in myStringList)
{
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(item);
}
```

Obviously, I am looking for generic answers that are not actually dependent on data columns or strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
var newList = list.ConvertAll(x => new Something(x));
list.ForEach(x => DoSomething(x));
```

These methods are defined by th `List<T>` class.

If you have an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use LINQ:

```
var newEnumerable = enumerable.Select(x => new Something(x));
```

Comment: Worth noting ForEach is only available on List<T>, that Linq does not directly implement IEnumerable<T> ForEach however it can be easily added yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Call [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx)

```
List<DataColumn> result = myStringList.Aggregate(
  new List<DataColumn>(),
  (list, item) => { list.Add(item); return list; }
);

return result;
```

---

That said, foreach statement is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, although not all of them are LINQ specific. ForEach is just a List method. For your two examples:

```
myStringList.ForEach(x => columnList.Add(x));
// assumes myStringList is a List<T>... otherwise convert your enumerable using ToList()
```

The ForEach method takes an Action and lets you perform some logic on each item. So if you want to do transformations, it's easy enough combining with select:

```
myStringList.Select(x => new DataColumn(x))
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => columnList.Add(x));
// transforms each element of the string by adding some text, then calling foreach 
// on the items
```

Answer (score 0):

myStringList.ForEach(item => myDataTable.Columns.Add(item));

EDIT: that's not Linq. Sorry, my mistake.